# Using File GDB API .NET Wrapper in ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: asp.net, file-geodatabase

I am trying to use the File GDB API (1.2) .NET wrapper in an asp.net web service with no luck.  The website will not load spitting out error:  "Could not load file or assembly 'Esri.FileGDBAPI.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

The .NET Wrapper works perfectly fine in a windows form application from my machine.  Just to rule out the obvious:

1. Esri.GileGDBAPI.dll, FileGDBAPI.dll, and FileGDBAPID.dll all are sitting in the bin of the website (along with OpenTK dll's)
2. I have the prerequisite OpenTK installed
3. Latest VC Runtime distributable installed.
4. Website is targeting .NET 4.0

The fact that it runs fine in a windows form application gives me confidence that I have everything I need on my machine.

Does anyone have any other ideas and/or has anyone successfully used the .net wrapper in a .net webservice?

UPDATE:  With the help of fuslogvw in the post I marked as the answer, I was able to to get the web service working after the directory containing the FileGDBAPI.dll and FileGDBAPID.dll was added to the 'Path' variable.

Comment: I hava this problem in ASP.NET too.I can't resolve this problem with many ways.Did you resolved this problem now?

Comment: I ultimately got it working by making sure the native dlls were in a folder in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling Fusion logging and inspect it with [Fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to at least determine the reason for the assembly load failure: [Debugging Assembly Loading Failures](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314052834/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You might also try setting the application pool in which your website is running to the 32-bit mode.

The setting is called "Enable 32-bit applications" and you can find it under application pool's advanced setting in the IIS administration dashboard.